# "identify" vs "distinguish" to seperate two things?

Tags: meaning

1. How to Identify Difference Between True Lover and Fake Lover
2. How to distinguish Between True Lover and Fake Lover

Are they the same?

Comment: Could you add more context? Knowing the full sentence and how it's being used could help us give you a better answer.

Comment: This sort of question can usually be answered by consulting a good dictionary such as [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) or [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english) or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/). Take a look; and if you are still confused, come back and tell us what confuses you.

Comment: @StoneyB ,Yes dude, I looked at the dictionary, but I'm confused. Are these two words interchangeable?

Comment: No, they are not generally interchangeable... I can post an answer that will clarify to some degree but if you won't give more info about what you're actually trying to say, it may not be a **good** answer. :)

Comment: What in the definitions makes you think they could be interchangeable?

Comment: **This** is exactly why I asked you to give examples... you're not asking for the difference between **identify** and **distinguish**... you're asking for the difference between **identify the difference** and **distinguish**... which are about the same... because the definition of **distinguish** revolves around *identifying the difference* between things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a subtle difference and they have a variety of uses... if you could flesh out your question a bit more, I can adjust my answer to better suit your needs.

**Identify** is used when you're trying to figure out what something is:

> How do you identify if a shape is a square?
>
> Identify this state.

**Distinguish** has more of the implication that you're trying to separate two (or more) things:

> How do you distinguish between a square and a hexagon?
>
> Can you distinguish green from red? If not, you may be colorblind.